# Get difference between instance and parent of instance's properties

Tags: php, reflection

```
abstract class foo
{
    public $blah;
}

class bar extends foo
{
    public $baz;
}
```

Given that I have a `foo` class that inherits from the abstract `bar` class how would I get an array of the instance variables that exist only on `bar` but not on `foo` (i.e. properties that are defined on the `bar` level)? In the example above I would want `baz` but not `blah`.

Comment: With reflection. Has been asked before. However what are you trying to do if I may ask? Also technically all instance variables, including the inherited ones, exist with bar - that is how inheritance works.  *Edit:*  Example how it is done for class constants which is sort of comparable: [Get the defining class for a constant in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11821137/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hakre said, use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/reflectionclass). Grab the class's parent class, and do a diff on the properties, like so:

```
function get_parent_properties_diff( $obj) {
    $ref = new ReflectionClass( $obj);
    $parent = $ref->getParentClass();
    return array_diff( $ref->getProperties(), $parent->getProperties());
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
$diff = get_parent_properties_diff( new bar());
foreach( $diff as $d) {
    echo $d->{'name'} . ' is in class ' . $d->{'class'} . ' and not the parent class.' . "\n";
}
```

See it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/b7N8Sh), which outputs:

```
baz is in class bar and not the parent class.
```

Comment: You can also make use of [`ReflectionProperty::getDeclaringClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdeclaringclass.php) to test this per property. Just an additional note.